# JPA how PESSIMISTIC_READ is mapped to oracle database?

Tags: oracle, jpa, locking

JPA how the Lock mode PESSIMISTIC_READ is mapped to oracle database? For mysql,

```
select * from TableName lock in share mode
```

How about oracle database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between LockModeType Jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062635/difference-between-lockmodetype-jpa)

Comment: no. it is about different lock modes, not about mapping to specific databases.

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062635/difference-between-lockmodetype-jpa) it was written that `select ... for update nowait` is used. I vote to close this question as duplicate.

Comment: And how something is implemented depends on which jpa provider ...